# Add web chart part to page

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I already created a list in which I added a content type. The list is for Research. There are different kinds of Research, so all of them will be placed in this list. Every Research type has its own chart. When the user is adding values in the form (list), the chart must be updated. I tried to add the web chart, but when I tried to connect it to the web part of the Research type, it says "Your page does not contain any Web Parts that are capable of providing data to your chart Web Part". How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

use **highcharts**  . which is basically works with jQuery

Comment: It's not possible to do it without it?

Comment: not al all. its a one way to show out charts on web pages.

Comment: OK, can you please tell me how to achieve it with HighCharts? I have no knowledge of web development.